# Return text value from Handlebars helper

Tags: handlebars.js, registerhelper

For some reason I cannot return the value created from a custom handlebars helper.  The value will console log out, but will not return 'to print'.

The helper uses a translation Class via the Google translate API.  The class works and I get translations - as said in console.log, but I need to return the translation to the template.

Here is the helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('translate',function(text){
  var transconfig = {
    from:'en',
    to:'es',
    api_key:'Google translate API key', // use your own key
    callback:function(translatedText){
      console.log('translated text', translatedText );
     }
   };
  translator.translateLanguage('text to translat',transconfig);
})
```

The template might look a bit like this ....

```
<script id="xyz-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h1>{{translate data.title}}</h1>
</script>
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: There is no return statement in your function, but I suspect that won't matter because the `translator.translateLangauge` call is probably [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript). You shouldn't put external API calls into a helper. You should translate your data _before_ passing it to your template method.

Comment: OK NP shame .... ...